# WebApp does not work when VPN is enabled

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn, webapps

I am running a WebApp on port 8080. The server running this app also needs to have an outbound VPN connected at all times. I am using OpenVPN on Ubuntu 20 server.

Once the VPN is connected I can no longer access the webaapp, for example on https://servername.com:8080

I assume this is because of routing. The web server is responding to my browser via the VPN which makes my browser abort the connection because the response differs from the sending request.

Is there a way in the routing table or something that I can get around this? Somehow if a request is sent directly to my web server it will respond outside of the VPN and go back over the regular NIC?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 or 20.10? NetworkManager or networkd?

Comment: I am using the .netplan files. So Is that NetworkManager?

Comment: No, it's different. Does your Netplan YAML have a `renderer:` line?

Comment: I am using networkd! Checked by looking for the service

Comment: This solution is worth a try: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317187/318849 . I think you should redirect using source port 8080